# Why does cordova-plugin-nativestorage work on browser but not on phone

Tags: cordova-plugins, phonegap-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app, phonegap, cordova-nativestorage

I am using the Phonegap CLI to serve my project and my plugin version is: 2.3.1
So, I wrote the following code to execute after the device is ready:

```js
NativeStorage.getItem("abcd",function(){
   console.log("success");alert("success");
  },function(){
   console.log("fail");alert("failed :)");
  });
```

This works perfectly when I am testing it on my browser. However, when I open this app on my android phone, the NativeStorage code does not work at all.

I used weinre to debug my app:

I got the error: ReferenceError: NativeStorage is not defined
[image]

I also removed the plugin and all the platforms and reinstalled them again; however, I am still getting the same error.

Can you please help me find the issue ?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't want to work with localStorage?

Comment: LocalStorage is unpredictable in iOS (http://gonehybrid.com/dont-assume-localstorage-will-always-work-in-your-hybrid-app/) and I need my app to be available in iOS

Comment: @TakshPratapSingh could you tell us where in your code are you calling this snippet. Maybe a smaller representative use-case which replicates your issue. Usually, this sorta problem is related to deviceready, but you mentioned in comments that you have already considered.

Answer (score 0):

**Are you waiting that your device is ready, before you are calling the NativeStorage plugin?**

In your index.js you should add something like the following code for the device handling.

```
if (window.cordova) {
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}
```

Note: If you want to use your app in the browser without the Cordova container, you should define an else branch like this. If its not a Cordova container, it will jump to the else branch and execute the function immediately.

```
if (window.cordova) {
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
} else {
  onDeviceReady();
}
```

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false)

- Parameter 1 - "deviceready": The name of the event
- Parameter 2 - onDeviceReady: The name of your function to starts your application.
  The name can of course differ to my name.
- Parameter 3 - false
  (optional): A Boolean value that specifies whether the event should
  be executed in the capturing or in the bubbling phase. (Source:
  w3schools.com)

For more information about the addEventListener: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_addeventlistener.asp

In your "onDeviceReady" function or later, you can now call the plugins you have defined in the config.xml

E.g.:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
  //call your plugins
  NativeStorage.getItem(<...>);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I was already checking for deviceready but the plugin simpy doesn't work on my phone. Actually, I remember reading somewhere that plugins can be used on the phone only when using the built app, not while using the phonegap developer app. Is this true?